# Deducing type of a global variable

Tags: c++, c++11, global-variables

Let's say I have a global variable declared in a header:

```
extern long global_var;
```

it would be reasonable to let compiler then deduce type when variable is defined in a source:

```
auto global_var;
```

I see at least some pros:

- avoiding code duplication, ie when we change type in header then do not have to change it in source file
- less error prone, if variable is not declared previously, it would not compile

Similar could work for static members of a class.

But currently that does not seem to be possible. Are there cons that outweigh those benefits?

Comment: *How* would the compiler be able to deduce the type? Just seeing `auto global_var;` (or even `extern auto global_var;`) there's no way for the compiler to know what type the variable is, especially if it's just a declaration with the definition and initialization in another translation unit.

Comment: Are there cons that outweigh those benefits? These things are resolved at linkage. So it's up to linker. Consequently, the compiler won't have a clue how to deduce `auto`.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg compiler would be able to deduce the type because it is declared explicitly in header, then in source file it already knows what the type is.

Comment: @101010 how it is resolved is irrelevant, when you define variable in cpp file it must much type in header, this way it would be automatic and what is more important enforced

Comment: I see no real drawback, but no real benefits either. `decltype` would suffice. It also makes it harder to know the variable type from the code.

Answer (score 1):

One way to avoid having to remember the type name of `global_var` and still get the right type for the compiler is to use `decltype`.

```
extern int global_var;


...


decltype(global_var) global_var;
```

The only downside of this approach is that you'll have to make the declaration of the variable available to the compiler before its definition.

Of course, it works for `static` member variables of classes too.

See it working at http://ideone.com/W1WToV.

Comment: Did not think about it this way, thanks. I don't really see that as downside, but rather upside. Only downside for this methot IMHO that it is verbose, especially for static members, but that can be done by macro.

Comment: @Slava, a macro will definitely make it less repetitive and less error prone.

Comment: So something like `#define GLOBAL_VAR_DEF(x) decltype(x) x` then `GLOBAL_VAR_DEF(abc) = 123;`

Comment: @Slava, that's the mechanism. I wouldn't use `GLOBAL_VAR_DEF`. I would use a more generic macro, `DEFINE_VARIABLE`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a global type for your global:

```
using global_var_type =  long;
extern global_var_type global_var;
```

And then

```
global_var_type global_var;
```

With no need to re-edit if you change the type (you will have to recompile of course)

Comment: I think to generate new type for every variable is little bit too much (including static members of a class)

Comment: You wanted types to be changable without re-editting.  Aliases do this for you.  Now I don't understand what you want. The compiler to read your mind?

Comment: Types to be changable is not the main reason, main one to make program less error prone.

Comment: But the linker won't allow type mismatches between `extern` variables anyway.

Comment: Is such behaviour required by standard? `ld` from linux only validates size, not type. Just checked.